# Magento 2 Checkout Page after place order take more time

Tags: magento2, checkout, success-message, loading

Frontend place order first order show in backend and after 4 to 5 min frontend redirect success page.I have remove/disable all third party module and set default theme but not success.And i have use magento 2 default checkout.

Please help what issue is cause.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you **install blackfire.io tool or another tool that you can use to perform some profiling**, see where exactly it hangs and why. There isn't much we can tell from the behavior you mentioned unless you debug this and see where exactly does the request spend most of that time.